# Run code after the user has finished moving the window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've made a WPF application and one of my windows is required to go fullscreen, however I'm trying to get it so that if the user drags the window to another monitor it will automatically resize to suit that monitor.

I've tried the previewmouse up down events, mouse up down events to set a bool that the window is being dragged to prevent the code from executing, however this does not appear to work and the window is still trying to resize itself as its being dragged and the mouse is down (as if mousedown is being set to false)

The code that resizes the window is in the window located changed event

Is there any other ways that can effectively detect that the mouse is down and dragging the window to another monitor before executing the code to resize it to suit?

Whilst the user is dragging the window I dont want the code to resize it to be executed, once the user has finished dragging the window, the code to resize the window to the new screen should be executed.

Currently I cant get the code to run after the window has finished moving.
Upon further investigation, no mouse up events are fired after the mouse is released on the title border.

Comment: Please add a proper title. Few people read questions with incomplete or confusing titles, resulting in no answers

Comment: Just done that, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can override OnPreviewMouseMove for any UI element.

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
```

Then using the event args of that handler (of type MouseEventArgs) - you check if the left mouse button is pressed (indicating a drag).

```
e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed
```

Comment: I've updated the question and description with some additional detail, this works better than mouse move, however the window will never resize because e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed will never be true in the locationchanged event

Answer (score 0):

When you start dragging a maximized Window, the size changes. This is how Windows behaves and is natural to a user. On end of drag you can just set the state back to maximized.

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: I've updated the question and description with some additional detail, I have code to maximize the window however cant get it to only run when the user has finished moving the window

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked this event ? Sounds like what you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.locationchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yup, unfortunately it executes as the window is being changed i need something to execute after the window location has been changed